# How to convert hour extracted from date to hour + (date in hours)?

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

```
       0   1
0      6   7
1     11  13
2      7   8
3     16  17
4      5   6
5     18  20
6      8   9
7     13  13
8      3   4
9     13  14
10     5   6
11    17  17
12    11  12
13    21  22
14    19  20
15     6   7
16    13  14
17    12  13
18     3   4
19     3   4
20    11  13
21    12  13
22     4   5
23     5   6
24    13  14
25    13  14
26     1   3
27     6   6
28     4   5
29    12  14
  ..  ..
9689  10  11
9690  16  17
9691  13  13
9692   8   8
9693   8   9
9694  12  13
9695  13  13
9696  19  19
9697  14  14
9698  13  13
9699  14  14
9700  19  19
9701  13  13
9702  19  19
9703  14  14
9704  13  13
9705   8   9
9706   7   8
9707   7   8
9708  17  18
9709  22  22
9710  12  12
9711   7   8
9712  20  22
9713  11  12
9714  16  17
9715   7   7
9716  24   2
9717   8  10
9718   8  10
```

I have this dataframe where the columns correspond to an hour of the 24hour clock (1 to 24). These are currently extracted from the date using:

```
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(POXTime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
POXHour = time.hour
```

I am wondering if anyone can tell me a way I can add 24 to each entry that is a day subsequent (based on the first date that appears in the list being 1 to 24 hours). For example the first 1000 or so rows of this dataframe are from 01/05/2018, then it goes on to 02/05/2018 but still says "17" for the 17th hour where I want it to say "41" (17+24)... and so on for each subsequent day. Hope this makes sense! Can anyone help?

EDIT

Here is the first few rows of the data without the date/time being stripped for just the hour:

```
   POETime           POXTime
0     01/05/2018 05:33  01/05/2018 06:31
1     01/05/2018 10:56  01/05/2018 12:18
2     01/05/2018 06:22  01/05/2018 07:21
3     01/05/2018 15:17  01/05/2018 16:40
4     01/05/2018 04:19  01/05/2018 05:16
5     01/05/2018 17:41  01/05/2018 19:02
6     01/05/2018 07:56  01/05/2018 08:51
```

EDIT2
Here is an example of where the date changes...

```
1360    01/05/2018 02:18    01/05/2018 02:18
1361    01/05/2018 21:47    01/05/2018 21:47
1362    01/05/2018 11:50    01/05/2018 11:50
1363    01/05/2018 07:28    01/05/2018 07:52
1364    01/05/2018 00:09    01/05/2018 00:09
1365    01/05/2018 15:52    01/05/2018 17:36
1366    01/05/2018 08:27    01/05/2018 09:32
1367    01/05/2018 04:57    01/05/2018 06:06
1368    01/05/2018 09:58    01/05/2018 11:44
1369    01/05/2018 16:32    01/05/2018 17:22
0   02/05/2018 02:17    02/05/2018 03:24
1   02/05/2018 12:08    02/05/2018 13:28
2   02/05/2018 06:31    02/05/2018 07:39
3   02/05/2018 15:20    02/05/2018 16:57
4   02/05/2018 04:06    02/05/2018 05:13
5   02/05/2018 17:18    02/05/2018 18:53
6   02/05/2018 08:32    02/05/2018 09:24
7   02/05/2018 02:36    02/05/2018 03:30
8   02/05/2018 03:40    02/05/2018 04:30
```

which I want to output as...

```
1360    01/05/2018 02:18    01/05/2018 02:18        3   3
1361    01/05/2018 21:47    01/05/2018 21:47        10  10
1362    01/05/2018 11:50    01/05/2018 11:50        12  12
1363    01/05/2018 07:28    01/05/2018 07:52        8   8
1364    01/05/2018 00:09    01/05/2018 00:09        1   1
1365    01/05/2018 15:52    01/05/2018 17:36        16  18
1366    01/05/2018 08:27    01/05/2018 09:32        9   10
1367    01/05/2018 04:57    01/05/2018 06:06        5   7
1368    01/05/2018 09:58    01/05/2018 11:44        10  12
1369    01/05/2018 16:32    01/05/2018 17:22        17  18
1   02/05/2018 02:17    02/05/2018 03:24        27  28
2   02/05/2018 12:08    02/05/2018 13:28        37  38
3   02/05/2018 06:31    02/05/2018 07:39        31  32
4   02/05/2018 15:20    02/05/2018 16:57        40  41
5   02/05/2018 04:06    02/05/2018 05:13        29  30
6   02/05/2018 17:18    02/05/2018 18:53        42  43
6   02/05/2018 08:32    02/05/2018 09:24        33  34
7   02/05/2018 02:36    02/05/2018 03:30        27  28
8   02/05/2018 03:40    02/05/2018 04:30        28  29
```

Comment: How are we supposed to tell from your provided data when the day changes.  You should really include that as a column.

Comment: @chrisz I have added an explanation at the bottom of the post which should help

Answer (score 0):

There is different option, one way is:

```
ref_date_POE = min(df['POETime']) # or any date you want
df['POEHours'] = (df['POETime'] - ref_date_POE).dt.days*24 + df['POETime'].dt.hour +1
```

Here `(df['POETime'] - ref_date_POE).dt.days` give you the number of days between the date in `df['POETime']` and `ref_date_POE`, so *24 give you what you want. For the +1, it seems that you have 3 when it's 2:18 and `df['POETime'].dt.hour` would give you 2, so just add 1.

Comment: I have tried this but getting errors relating to trying to subtract a string from a string etc.. Tried converting the orginial df to date.time but it doesn't like that either. Any ideas?

Comment: @djj1994 can you tell me what it did not like btw?